# Python GRPc log failed connection attempts

Tags: python, logging, grpc, grpc-python

I have a GRPc server written in Python and I just implemented TSL encryption.

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
test_pb2_grpc.add_TestServicer_to_server(TestServicer(), server)

with open(SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY, 'rb') as f:
    private_key = f.read()
with open(SERVER_CERTIFICATE, 'rb') as f2:
    certificate_chain = f2.read()

server_credentials = grpc.ssl_server_credentials(((private_key, certificate_chain,),))

server.add_secure_port('[::]:{}'.format(SERVER_PORT), server_credentials)
server.start()
```

if I try to connect without the certificate

```
with grpc.insecure_channel(target='localhost:50051') as channel:

    stub = test_pb2_grpc.TestStub(channel)
    guide_get_one_feature(stub, Test_pb2.UserInfo("test"))
```

I get this error on the server

```
E0712 14:30:29.748944000 123145353949184 ssl_transport_security.cc:1238] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
```

I've already set my logger to write in a file

```
logger = logging.getLogger(name)
filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("{}.log".format(filename)))
```

But I can't make it to log the grpc error. Is there a way to handle these errors somehow?

Comment: Do you want to have the ability to connect to the server using either a secure connection or an insecure connection? I could be wrong, but it seems to me that your server only allows secure connections are the moment.

Comment: @zmike no, I want when someone tries to connect with an insecure connection to be able to log the error in my log file. (to be able to log any error coming from grpc to my log file)